# declaring static variable in the class

Tags: c#

I am getting error while diclaring collName as static variable in Student class.
Could any one help me finding it.

```
class Student
    {
        public int SId;
        public string SName;
        public Student(int SId)
        {
            this.SId = SId;
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor is called");
        }
        static string coll = new string ();
        cool = "RVIM"
```

I am getting below error.

```
Error   1   Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration C:\Users\amruthap\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Student.cs   18  14  ConsoleApplication1
Error   2   'string' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments  C:\Users\amruthap\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Student.cs   17  37  ConsoleApplication1
Error   3   'ConsoleApplication1.Student.coll' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'   C:\Users\amruthap\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Student.cs   18  9   ConsoleApplication1
    }
```

Comment: getting error is too generic. you should at minimum include the error message in your question

Comment: There are multiple errors here. Which one do you want help with.

Comment: What is cool? and why is it being assigned where it is?

Comment: Is coll and cool the same variable - typos ? Where is collName ?

Comment: not cool, try `static string coll = "RVIM";`

Comment: Yes Jodrell. I got it. Cant i treat a string variable as string object.

Comment: @AmruthaPerumal - you can. The problem is here is that you can't have assignments (which are not field initializers) / string.method calls floating around in a type definition. It has to be enclosed in a method. So if you place the assignment in a method (e.g. a static ctor), it'd be valid C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call the string constructor ...try treating it as a value type

static string coll = " " ;

Comment: To be precise, string is not a value type - it is a reference type. What you are doing here is assigning a literal value to a string variable.

Answer (score 4):

You can't call the default string constructor - [String class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) has no ctor taking 0 parameters.. Try setting coll to ""

Answer (score 2):

string doesnt contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

second thing  `cool = "RVIM"`  `=` invalid token  in class struct or interface member declaration.